# SSRS: How to get count of equal ID of two columns after filter

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following table (Dataset2):

[image]

```
ACCOUNT_ID
8d82a329-f23e-ec11-8c62-000d3a8252c3
8988e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
8988e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
8b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
8b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
8b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
8b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
8b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
8b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9788e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9788e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
b788e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
b788e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
b988e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf

CCA_AGENT_ID
8788e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9788e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9788e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9988e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9988e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9988e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9988e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9988e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9988e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9788e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9788e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
9b88e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
b788e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
b788e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf
b988e53a-1158-ec11-8f8f-002248171edf

CJ_ID
8098037c-6d89-ec11-93b0-000d3a82c9fa
ac101b6f-478e-ec11-b400-000d3a817222
ac101b6f-478e-ec11-b400-000d3a817222
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
ac101b6f-478e-ec11-b400-000d3a817222
ac101b6f-478e-ec11-b400-000d3a817222
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
fabc5219-198e-ec11-b400-000d3a817bb3
ddb8ebf6-468e-ec11-b400-000d3a817222
ddb8ebf6-468e-ec11-b400-000d3a817222
9ed93c43-478e-ec11-b400-000d3a817222
```

I want to filter first by CJ_ID from the value of ID on DataSet1 (Primary dataset) then count all rows where ACCOUNT_ID = AGENT_ID

The DataSet2 contains this fields:

[image]

I created a Calculated field with the expression below with name AccEqualsAgent:

[image]

I set this expression on the textbox and gives 0 value:

[image]

However, I try to aggregate the value of AccEqualsAgent field and it displays 22:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be directly in your dataset query, but assuming you cannot do that for some reason then you can do this as follows.

Add a calculated field to Dataset2 from the DataSet properties panel.

Call the fields something like `AccEqualsAgent` and set the expression to

```
=IIF(Fields!ACCOUNT_ID.Value = Fields!AGENT_ID.Value, Fields!CJ_ID.Value, "")
```

Now you can simply do your `LOOKUPSET()` against this new field and count the results, like this...

```
=LookupSet(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!AccEqualsAgent.Value, Fields!AccEqualsAgent.Value, "Dataset2").Length
```

This will give you the number of records found in the lookupset

---

**Update with working example**

---

I recreated your data for DataSet2 from the sample data provided. All data was stored as datatype = UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
I then created DataSet1 by just taking a unique list of CJ_ID from DataSet2. I did this by hand so they are not actually linked in anyway.

I then added a calculated column to DataSet2 called `AccEqualsAgent` using the following expression

```
=IIF(Fields!ACCOUNT_ID.Value = Fields!CCA_AGENT_ID.Value, Fields!CJ_ID.Value, "")
```

[image]

I then added two tables to the report just so we can see the data we are dealing with.

In reverse order....

The second table is just a dump of DataSet2 including the calculated field.

The first table is a dump of DataSet1 but also include an expression to count the match records as per your question.

[image]

The expression used is as follows

```
=LookupSet(
    Fields!ID.Value, 
    Fields!AccEqualsAgent.Value, 
    Fields!AccEqualsAgent.Value, "DataSet2"
    ).Length
```

The final design including datasets etc., looks something like this..

[image]

When the report is run we get the following...

[image]

Comment: I tried the similar expression above but it gives me an #Error output. Specifically when I use AccEqualsAgent field on LookupSet but when I use other fields within the dataset, it has no error.

The expression for AccEqualsAgent is like this:
IIF(Fields!ACCOUNT_ID.Value = Fields!Agent_IDValue.Value, Fields!CJ_ID.Value, "")

Comment: I tried to use Count() on the AccEqualsAgent field but it displays 22 in which it still counts all of rows without filter.

Comment: Try changing the end of the calculated field expression to from `, "")` to `, Nothing)` . I can't test it at the moment but if this does not work I'll try to recreate the data later.

Comment: I updated the value to Nothing and it became 0.

Comment: can you edit your question and add the dataset sample you posted as an image, as text so I can reproduce it.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: As I asked, can you edit your question and add the dataset sample you posted as an image, as text so I can reproduce it. I'm not going to sit there and type a load of sample GUIDs into a table.

Comment: Apologies, I already updated the question. Since I cannot get all columns, I pasted each columns instead

Comment: Sorry for late reply, we decided for a different approach but I tried the example above and it works as well. Thanks!